# Using the Pythagorean theorem with Java

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I'm trying to create this program that essentially solves the 3rd value of a right triangle.

So the hypotenuse will always be 1, and one of the values (lets call it 'x') will be greater than or equal to -1 but less than or equal to 1.

First, I created a loop to include all values of x:

```
   int i = 10;

   while (i >= -10)
   {
       double x = i / 10.0;
       i--;

       System.out.println(x);

    }
```

Now, I get a nice list that gives me the values for x. I now need to use that to calculate the values of the third length of the triangle. I can do this using the Pythagoras Theorem. Here it is:

```
double firsty = Math.pow(1, 2) - Math.pow(x, 2);
double y = Math.sqrt(firsty);
```

When I put this in the while loop and then write a print statement for y, the results are formatted in a way that lists the first value of x, then the first value of y, then the second value of x, and then the second value of y. How can I change the formatting so that it just has two separate rows, one column that has the values of x and another column that has the values of y?

What I tried doing originally is using an array to hold the values of x in, but I can't calculate the values of the 3rd length by using an array without getting the compiler to yell 'ERROR' at me!

Using the printf function is what needs to be done (pretty sure), but I get a error message when I use printf for the output of x and y.

Comment: What values were you expecting to see for `y`?  And what values are you actually getting?

Comment: Don't forget to take the square root of `y`.

Comment: Okay, I feel like an idiot for not square rooting it. Now that values are correct, but the formatting is wrong. Here is the output:                  1.0                                                                                   0.0
   0.9
   0.4358
   0.8
   0.599
   0.7
   0.714
   0.6
   0.8
   0.5
   0.86
   0.4
   0.916
   0.3
   0.953
   0.2
   0.979
   0.1
   0.99
   0.0
   1.0
   -0.1
   0.9949
   -0.2
   0.97972
   -0.3
   0.953
-0.4
   0.9165
   -0.5
   0.866
   -0.6
   0.8
   -0.7
   0.714
   -0.8
   0.599
   -0.9
   0.435
   -1.0
   0.0

Comment: It's a list of numbers, starting with the first value of x and then the first value of y, then the second value of x and then the second value of y, and the list goes on. How can I change the list so that it displays all the values of x in one row, and all the values of y in a different row?

Comment: Why don't you store all the `x` values in one array, and all the `y` values in another; then iterate through each array when it comes time to print them?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it appears you've forgotten to take the square root of `y`. The Pythagorean formula is c<sup>2</sup> = a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>. So, I think you're looking for

```
double y = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(1, 2) - Math.pow(x, 2));
```

and to format it you might use a `DecimalFormat` or `String.format` like

```
String str = String.format("%.2f", y); // <-- 2 decimal places.
```

Comment: Alright, I fixed the square root issue. Thanks! But using String.format still makes the formatting look wrong. Right now, it prints a list of numbers, starting with the first value of x and then the first value of y, then the second value of x and then the second value of y. I'm trying to making it print all the values of x in one column, and all the values of y in a different column. I tried using DecimalFormat, but it still didn't help.

Comment: Include a newline (\n) in the format where you want a line break.

Comment: Show us how you're printing it, because English isn't describing it adequately (and showing the output doesn't really help).

Comment: System.out.println(str);

Comment: Try something like `String.format("%.2f %.2f%n", x, y);` but it's really hard to tell when everything is on one line in your comment.